# Is there a way in python to identify the exact values from a dataframe with multiple independent variables that generate these outliers?

Tags: python, xgboost, outliers

I predicted a model with the xgboost algorithm on python and I graphed the predicted values vs the actal ones on a scatterplot (see image).
As you can see, there are several outliers (I drew a circle around them) who greatly damage the model and I would like to get rid of them.
Is there a way in python to identify the exact values from a dataframe with multiple independent variables that generate these outliers?[predicted vs actual values]

[image: predVSactual]

Answer (score 0):

There is something called an anomaly/outlier detection system, should check that out.

[Here is a link](https://machinelearningmedium.com/2018/05/02/anomaly-detection/)

Answer (score 0):

There are several algorithms which are available in python for multivariate anomaly detection in sklearn like DBSCAN , Isolation Forest , One Class SVM etc and generally isolation forest is deemed have good anomaly/outlier detection when the dataset has high attributes. However more before using anomaly/outlier detection algorithms one needs to identify if these values are actually outlier or whether they are natural behaviour for the dataset. If yes then rather than removing the records one might have to normalize /bin or apply other feature engineering technique/ look at more complex algorithms to fit the data. What if the relation of the target variable and the independent variables is non-linear?